# Mudar campo do banco de dados automático após determinada hora

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Bom eu tenho um campo na minha tabela que se chama status, preciso fazer que meu banco atualize esse campo automaticamente caso o visitante não saia da empresa após as 18:00.

Alguém sabe como eu começo? estou usando Oracle

Comment: Como vai fazer para saber que o visitante está na empresa? Se é feito um registro de ponto, pode monitorar através desse registro de ponto, sendo que quando alguem sai,bate o ponto e atualiza o status para "fora da empresa" se não mantem com o status atual "esta na empresa".

Comment: È uma tela de cadastro de visitante e visita, o cara vai cadastrar como status pendente, e caso ele não saia da empresa até 6 horas eu preciso atualizar a tela para Ausente

Comment: Procedure é a solução para o teu problema.

Pode encontrar mais infos aqui: https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-stored-procedures-e-cursores-no-oracle-sql-server-e-firebird-e-postgresql/33023

https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-stored-procedures-e-cursores-no-oracle-sql-server-e-firebird-e-postgresql/33023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure é a solução para o teu problema.

Desenvolver sua Store Procedure:

Sintaxe báisca:

```
    CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_nome
      [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]
  IS
      [declaration_section]
  BEGIN
      executable_section
  [EXCEPTION
      exception_section]
  END [procedure_nome];
```

Exemplo de como iria ficar aplicado ao problema:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure AtualizaStatusVisitante

  BEGIN

   UPDATE visitante SET vistiante_status = 'Ausente' WHERE vistiante_status = 'Pendente';

  COMMIT;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'Ocorreu um erro');
  END;
```

Nesse exemplo, executa um UPDATE quando o visitante estiver com `STATUS = Pendente`

Com a procedure criada hora de aplicar um agendamento, para isso será usado JOBs que permite criar esse tipo de atividade.

```
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                      what => 'begin PRC_sua_rotina; end;',
                      next_date => to_date('26-01-2018 20:41:52', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                      interval => 'TRUNC(sysdate+1) + 1/24*4');
  commit;
end;
```

Só altera aí o NEXT DATE pra data que tu quer que rode a PRIMEIRA vez. Depois, essa data será atualizada automaticamente pra data que der aquele "interval", ou seja, o próximo dia + 4 horas.

Fontes:

[Aqui1](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-stored-procedures-e-cursores-no-oracle-sql-server-e-firebird-e-postgresql/33023)

[Aqui2](http://glufke.net/oracle/viewtopic.php?t=1469)

[Aqui3](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/PL-SQL/Useproceduretoupdatetable.htm)

Comment: Isso que você escreveu se encaixa mais como comentário. Você não mostrou nenhuma solução, apenas colou links.

Comment: Essa é a solução, veja a pergunta dele. Ele começa com procedures. Obrigado por negativar e depois comentar. Posso remover o a resposta se for o caso.

Comment: Ou poderia melhorar, mostrando além das referências um trecho de código/explicação significativo

Comment: Eu, por exemplo, na minha ignorância de bancos Oracle não percebi como atender essa demanda via procedure, então sua resposta não me é útil caso eu tenha um problema parecido

Comment: Entendi o que você quer dizer. Pensando em um contexto além da pergunta. Vou elaborar um resposta coerente ao que você recomenda.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Obrigado pelo empurrão, Fiz as melhorias a minha resposta de forma que agregue valor ao comunidade. Aberto a sugestões.

Comment: Muito obrigado vou tentar usar o seu como exemplo ta bem explicado!

Comment: Consegui fazer a Procedure, mas quando executo o job dá um erro olha

Comment: ORA-01008: not all variables bound




Details:
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                      what => 'begin AtualizaStatusVisitante; end;',
                      next_date => to_date('26-01-2018 20:41:52', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                      interval => 'TRUNC(sysdate+1) + 1/24*12');
  commit;
end;
Error at line 1
ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: Vou verificar o problema.