# Executar Update Automático - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, scheduler, job

Eu frequentemente executo um `Update` no Oracle para alterar o status na minha base de dados, mas gostaria que essa atualização fosse executada automaticamente, uma vez por dia.

```
UPDATE inativa_produto set compras = 'N', estoque = 'N', distribuição = 'N' em que data_final <sysdate
```

A atualização acima verifica os dados da vigilância da inatividade do item e é a mesma para os dados atuais mais baixos ou o status das colunas (compras, estoque e distribuição) que são alteradas para `'N'`.

Nesse caso, como eu poderia criar um trabalho para executar ou atualizar acima todos os dias?

Comment: Relacionado: [Mudar campo do banco de dados automático após determinada hora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271790/3774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso você pode utilizar um Scheduler Job para realizar esse procedimento em uma frequência diária.

O ideal é que você trocasse os valores de 'S' e 'N' para 1 ou 0 pensando na questão de performance, mas seguindo o seu update acima, aconselho a você criar uma procedure dessa maneira:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_INATIVA_PRODUTO IS

BEGIN

UPDATE inativa_produto
   SET compras = 'N', estoque = 'N', distribuição = 'N'
 WHERE data_final < TRUNC(SYSDATE); 

END;
```

E criar um scheduler job utilizando o pacote dbms_scheduler do Oracle:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name            => 'NOME_DO_JOB',
                                job_type            => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                job_action          => 'P_INATIVA_PRODUTO',
                                start_date          => SYSDATE + INTERVAL '60' SECOND,
                                repeat_interval     => 'Freq=Daily;Interval=1',
                                end_date            => NULL,
                                job_class           => 'DBMS_JOB$',
                                enabled             => true,
                                auto_drop           => false,
                                comments            => '');
end;
/
```

Caso queira ler as documentações do Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI

Comment: Kauan, boa tarde! Muito obrigado pelo retorno.